# detecting comments in flex

Tags: c, flex-lexer

I am just learning flex.I have written a simple program to check the words of a given text file is verb or not and print them. I want to detect if there is any single or multi line comments in the input file (like c and c++ style comments)and print the entire comment to output. Is there a way to do that? My sample code is as follows:

```
%%

[\t]+

is   |

am   |

are  |

was  |

were {printf("%s: is a verb",yytext);}

[a-zA-Z]+ {printf("%s: is a verb",yytext);}

. |\n

%%

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){    
    yyin = fopen(argv[1], "r");    
    yylex();         
    fclose(yyin);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit more complicated. I suggest using [start conditions](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Start-Conditions.html) for handling the comments. Here's a lexer I quickly put together for this:

```
%option noyywrap
%x COMMENT_SINGLE
%x COMMENT_MULTI

%top{
/* for strndup */
#include <string.h>
}

%{
char* commentStart;
%}

%%

[\n\t\r ]+ { 
  /* ignore whitespace */ }

<INITIAL>"//" { 
  /* begin of single-line comment */ 
  commentStart = yytext; 
  BEGIN(COMMENT_SINGLE); 
}

<COMMENT_SINGLE>\n { 
  /* end of single-line comment */
  char* comment = strndup(commentStart, yytext - commentStart);
  printf("'%s': was a single-line comment\n", comment);
  free(comment); 
  BEGIN(INITIAL); 
}

<COMMENT_SINGLE>[^\n]+ { 
  /* suppress whatever is in the comment */
}

<INITIAL>"/*" { 
  /* begin of multi-line comment */
  commentStart = yytext; 
  BEGIN(COMMENT_MULTI); 
}

<COMMENT_MULTI>"*/" { 
  /* end of multi-line comment */
  char* comment = strndup(commentStart, yytext + 2 - commentStart);
  printf("'%s': was a multi-line comment\n", comment);
  free(comment); 
  BEGIN(INITIAL); 
}

<COMMENT_MULTI>. { 
  /* suppress whatever is in the comment */
} 

<COMMENT_MULTI>\n { 
  /* don't print newlines */
} 

is   |
am   |
are  |
was  |
were { 
  printf("'%s': is a verb\n", yytext); 
}

[a-zA-Z]+ { 
  printf("'%s': is not a verb\n", yytext); 
}

. { 
  /* don't print everything else */ 
}

%%

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){    
  yyin = fopen(argv[1], "r");    
  yylex();         
  fclose(yyin);
}
```

Note: the lexer code is already long enough so I ommitted any error checking.

Comment: your code id detecting every comment as multi line comment.single line comment is not being treated individually.Additionally is there any way to remove the /* and */ in output? @stj

Comment: Whenever I try it (generating with flex 2.5.39 and the default options), the above code treats single and multi-line comments individually. Can you provide input for which it treats them the same?

Comment: To remove the `/*` and `*/` from the multi-line comments, you need to adjust this line: `char* comment = strndup(commentStart, yytext + 2 - commentStart);` to look like this: `char* comment = strndup(commentStart + 2, yytext - 2 - commentStart);`

Comment: Isn't the original question answered by now?

Comment: It sounds like you are now looking for a rule to detect complete sentences (i.e. `I am a good boy`). For this you will have to be clear about the rules for where a sentence starts and where it ends. If the input to your lexer are just ASCII letters, whitespace and comments, that may be simple. However, if there is also punctuation, it will get very difficult. For example, how should your lexer handle this input: `I am a /* good */ boy [newline], e.g. I love to play cricket`?

Comment: can you please tell me how to detect any unfinished or ill formed comments? what I need to add in the code you suggested? @stj

Answer (score 1):

Single line comment
`\/\/.*\n {}`